# Matlab Mex file error

Tags: matlab

When I am running mex -setup in malab 2012b to configure the compiler I get the following error:

`C:\Program Files(x86)\MATLAB\R2012\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe` is not a valid Win32 application.

Actually this error is not in matlab command it pops up as box in front of me. Any idea?

Comment: Well, does that file exist and is it a valid executable?

Answer (score 0):

I googled your path, and found this:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/268579